# Call WCF Service through SQL CLR

Tags: wcf, sqlclr

I have followed all the steps in below link.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913668 - Method 2

But still I'm facing the same error

> 'Cannot load dynamically generated serialization assembly. In some
>   hosting environments assembly load functionality is restricted,
>   consider using pre-generated serializer. after creating xmlserializer
>   assembly'.

Pleae help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Referenced here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913668

MS SQL sandboxes .NET and doesn't allow you to do dynamic CLR generation. You can get around this by generating the assembly at compile-time using this as a post-build step:

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bin\sgen.exe" /force "$(TargetPath)"

The referenced article has a couple other options, but if your schema is pre-determined, sgen is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have gone through same article & followed Method2. generated.XmlSerializer.dll through VS command prompt & created assembly for that also in SQL. Still I'm facing the same error. Please help me.

Comment: Did you add this assembly to SQL?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I had added that also. But I was facing the same issue. After upgrading my sql to sql 2012, it started working properly without any other changes.